# Using awk to print statements inside files inside a tar.gz file?

Tags: bash, awk, tar

Have a tar.gz file, the file contains multiple .add files, which contains multiple rows of data.

Am trying to get column 1 of the rows of data without extracting tar.gz file.

Code used but doesn't work:
`tar -xvf FILENAME.tgz --to-command="awk 'BEGIN {print $1}'"`

Example of the contents of the .tgz file:

```
a.add
b.add
```

Example of the contents of a .add file:

```
2019|01|190|80
2020|03|172|65
2019|04|160|50
2018|12|165|48
```

Example of desired output:

```
2019
2020
2019
2018
```

*Summary:
I want to print first column of each row of data in multiple .add files which are compressed in a tar.gz file without extracting.*

Comment: You should provide a [mcve] so we can test your code and test fixes.  Show what output you expect, and what it does right now.  "doesn't work" is not much to go on.  As a beginner here, you should take the [tour] and read [ask].  Note you are missing a `"` at the end of your command.

Comment: this is minimal example. lot of people tend to say "you should.." instead of at least trying to read question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ tar xzf tar.gz --to-command="awk -F\| '{print \$1}'"
2019
2020
2019
```

Comment: It worked, is the only problem missing escape sequences?

Comment: `BEGIN` block is only executed once when the program is started, it won't be applied to every record in data. And then the quoting issue and the missing definition for field separator (`FS` or `-F` as I used to emphasize the removed `BEGIN` block).